# How can I force scaled-down svg images to line up next to each other instead of wrapping/getting pushed to the next line?

Tags: html, css, image, svg, dreamweaver

I have 6 svg images that I would like to appear in a row, like this:

logo_1 logo_2 logo_3 logo_4 logo_5 logo_6

They are of varying widths, but are all the same height, so I used the height property to scale them at the same ratio. That works to scale the svg, but for some reason the img container is still the full width of the layout grid, resulting in each image getting pushed to the next line, like this:

[..............................logo_1............................]

[..............................logo_2............................]

[..............................logo_3............................]

[..............................logo_4............................]

[..............................logo_5............................]

[..............................logo_6............................]

Here's the code that does that:

```
        <div class="gridContainer clearfix">
         <div class="sponsorLogo">
         <img src=_assets/images/logo_1.svg/>
         <img src=_assets/images/logo_2.svg/>
         <img src=_assets/images/logo_3.svg/>
         <img src=_assets/images/logo_4.svg/>
         <img src=_assets/images/logo_5.svg/>
         <img src=_assets/images/logo_6.svg/>
         </div>
       </div>

.sponsorLogo img {
text-align: center;
height: 3em;
}
```

I can get them to line up in a row when I use the width property, but that causes the images to have non-uniform heights, kind of like this:

logo_1 LOGO_2 LoGo_3 lOgO_4 LOgo_5 loGO_6 (you get the idea. hehe)

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.sponsorLogo img {
  text-align: center;
  height: 3em;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: sadly, that didn't work, but thank you for responding :)